Flagging endpoints are intermittently slow recently
Lately, when I click the flag button on a post, it takes roughly 2 seconds for the flag dialog to get a server response and for the flagging dialog to show up. Then when I submit my flag reason, it quite consistently takes roughly 1.5 seconds for the server to respond and for the flagging dialog to close.
It's not slow on Meta Stack Exchange, or other Stack Exchange sites, or even Meta Stack Overflow. It's just on SO. On the other sites, it's quite snappy. And other moderation actions on SO are still snappy, such as the delete-vote flow and up/down-voting.
The issue seems to be intermittent. I personally observe it most of the time, but sometimes the server only takes ~200ms to respond (which is how long it takes for it to respond to most of my other requests).
Question to the community: Is this happening to everyone? I know of at least one other user who says they noticed a slow-down. I'm surprised I don't think I've heard anyone else bring this up on meta yet.
Question to SO Inc.: Why is this happening? (and why is it only happening on SO and not MSO, MSE, SU, AU, SF, etc.?) Can you please address this?

I'm seeing the same thing. The dialog to flag this post came up almost immediately, but one on SO took quite a bit longer

I also saw that but I always thought it was my internet connection.

I see the same thing on SO.

I have the same problem. On [SO] it takes 2-3 seconds to open the flag menu.

I also get a slowdown when flagging with userscripts (eg. advanced flagging) and the SE API.

It also seems to bleed over to metasmoke. It's been slow for me for a long time (years) but the recent hiccups seem to have exacerbated it. For example, when opening a post's page, it renders basically only the title for a second or two.

No repro. It was measured as 0.88 seconds with a stopwatch. And more like 0.58 seconds, with reaction time subtracted. Using a 4G connection. And more or less cold (no flagging for the past few days (with many computer power cycles)).

@PeterMortensen it's an intermittent issue (from what I've seen). It happens with the close vote dialog for me, I used to chalk it off as network issues on my end but seems like others are also facing it.

Yesterday and the days before I had the same experience as described in the question and first comments, but today it seems to be normal again. The flag dialog comes up quickly when I try to flag something.

@jps I agree, it seems to have normalized again.

I used to experience similar things with the comment link or the close voting dialog. Not currently though. Perhaps they run microservices for specific features which can bog down so you experience it on a per-feature basis rather than for the entire site at once.

As comments here denote, this is no longer reproduceable, and seems to have been normalized since May 20th.
